# How show that this function is surjective?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

First. Let $(A, \leq)$ a poset, i define the following set:
$$I_{a}=\{x\in A | x \leq a \}$$

Let $\mathscr{I}=\{I_{a}\}_{a\in A}$ ordered by inclusion.

If $f:\mathscr{I} \rightarrow A$ is a function (i already proved that f is a function) definite as $a=f(I_a)$. How i can show that $f$ is surjective?

I've tryed proving that $ran f =A$, but i don't find a manner to show that $A \subseteq ran f $.

I appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what is " ran f" : I'd say you need "Im(f)" = the image of f, and also that $\;B=A\;$ ... Also, I'm not sure what's the need of order, posets and stuff: for any $\;a\in A\;$ , you have defined $\;I_a\;$ , so $\;f(I_a):=a\;$ is trivially surjective. Am I missing something?

Comment: if $b$ is any element in $A$, what is $f(I_b)$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio Sorry, you're absolutely right, I was wrong. I will correct it immediately.

Comment: Just a note that  "poset" has differing meanings. E.g.,in the set-theoretic topic of Forcing , a poset  is a  binary relation that is reflexive and transitive, but it is not assumed that $a\leq b\leq a$ implies $a=b$. A poset for which this implication holds is called strict. For the purposes of Forcing we can restrict ourselves to strict posets, but it is sometimes an inconvenience to do so.

Answer (score 0):

To prove surjectivity, all you need to to is to find, for each $x\in A$, some set in $X\in \mathscr{I}$ that maps to $x$, i.e. so that $f(X)=x$

Now, remember, each set in $X\in \mathscr{I}$ is actually $I_b$ for some $b\in A$, so all you need is (for each $x\in A$)to find some $b\in A$ such that $f(I_b)=x$.